# Is it possible to create a scrollview object without importing the android ScrollView class?

Tags: java, android, scrollview

I am trying to interpret the Java Code but I don't see how it is possible to create a ScrollView object without having the ScrollView class imported. Can anyone explain why this is possible? I don't see any ScrollView tags in the XML files either. This is the following code:

**MainActivity.Java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;

public class Form extends Activity {

    ScrollView sv;
    TableLayout myLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sv = new ScrollView(this);
        myLayout = new TableLayout (this);
        drawScreen();
    }
    //more code...
    ///....
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/textView"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import android.widget.*;
```

That imports everything under android.widget, including ScrollView.

Comment: so the dang asterisk represents all the android widgets to be imported huh? clever